# How to (and should I) put a path to user-installed python ahead of system-installed python?

Tags: terminal, bash, homebrew, python, path

I have a separate installation of Python 3.*, but the first python path in my `$PATH` variable is the path to system-installed Python. Is this how it should be?

I have added the path to user-installed Python using https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.Uydjga1dXDg, and it was popped at the end of `$PATH`.

Do I understand correctly that, in the current situation, when I run `pip`, `brew` etc. on python3 from bash, the changes will be applied to system-installed Python?

The fix I have got so far is to run `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH` every time I want to install or
update python, but it is not ideal.

NB: I went with `pyenv` solution as suggested by @bermudalocket. This pyenv [tutorial](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) was very useful.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can accomplish this by adding

```
export PATH="/path/to/python:"$PATH
```

to your `~/.zshrc` (or `~/.bash_profile` if you're not on Catalina).

I'd like to propose an alternative and suggest `pyenv`, available via Homebrew. You can set a specific Python version to be "global" (i.e. default everywhere) and/or "local" (i.e. using that version in a specific directory only).

E.g.:

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv global 2.7.16
cd ~/myProjects/MyProject
pyenv local 3.7.6
```

If you were to use Python in `~/myProjects/MyProject` it will default to `3.7.6`, and anywhere else `2.7.16`:

```
cd ~/some/other/directory
python --version
>> Python 2.7.16

cd ~/myProjects/MyProject
python --version
>> Python 3.7.6
```

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#homebrew-on-macos

Comment: Thank you! Would you know if setting it global or local (in some directories?) would affect the functioning of system's Python?

Comment: That's the beauty of it. If you run `pyenv versions` to see a list of available versions, one is `system`. This means you can run `<pyenv global/local> system`. Then if you're in a directory that uses the system version, any interactions you have with python will be with the system python.

Comment: Please add user manuals to answers in cases where one shouldn't be putting complete set of instructions. @bermudalocket

Comment: @ankii could you please direct me to the section of the Help Center where this requirement is stated? I do not see anything about it [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.

Comment: Yes there isn't a hard definition of the best answer, but put yourself in the shoes of OP and see if the answer is complete in itself? would it be able to counter any future problems that they might encounter? No. They asked another question, which has answers in the docs.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393571/ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260744/10063119 In case you're wondering why SO's things be applicable here, https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2509/313842 this is very apt too. Note my usage of *".. putting complete set of instructions..*"

Answer (score 3):

I installed Python 3.8 for macOS using the installer from python.org, not homebrew which is also installed on my Mac but rarely used. I think the first three lines below to my ~/.bash_profile was automatically added by the installer from python.org.

With those, any changes I make using `pip3` seem to affect only the 3.8 whereas those made via `pip` seem to affect only the 2.7 (which I believe comes installed with macOS). Because I did not use homebrew in installing Python 3.8 (or 2.7), I assume it is not relevant for either version of Python in my case. Hope these help.

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# I believe the two lines below were already in the file before the above were added
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```